# As fast as Or As fast

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions, comparisons, degree-of-comparison

> He is as clever if not cleverer than his brother.
>
> Ranjeet is as fast as or perhaps faster than Rohit.

Are both these sentences correct?

As per *Wren And Martin High School English Grammar And Composition* (BY N.D.V. PRASADA RAO S. CHAND), the first sentence is better like this:

> He is as clever as his brother, if not cleverer.

Or like this:

> He is as clever as, if not cleverer than, his brother.

(Chapter No-22 Conjunction.Page 255, example: This is as good as that, if not better.)

Now in second sentence conjunction OR has been used so can I use the punctuation comma here too? If I can, then how can the 2nd sentence be right?

Comment: "He is as clever as, if not cleverer than, his brother". The comma must include *than* as the whole phrase is parenthetical.

Comment: Yes sorry.. Thank you Matt.I think I was in bit of a rash.

Comment: 'in a bit of a rash' = 'ill-timed'?

Comment: @Edwin, no, just slightly allergic to something. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence isn't good English, because if you take out the "if not cleverer" you are left with *"He is as clever than his brother". It needs the word "as" to make it grammatical. And in both cases I would prefer to mark out the parenthetic clause with commas, so you get:

"He is as clever as, if not cleverer than, his brother."

"Ranjeet is as fast as, or perhaps faster than, Rohit."

It's perfectly ok to move the parenthetic clause to the end:

"He is as clever as his brother, if not cleverer [than him]."

"Ranjeet is as fast as Rohit, or perhaps faster [than him]."

(The bits in square brackets would usually be elided).

Neither version is "better" than the other. There is a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: Note that “He is as clever if not cleverer than his brother” is something you’re quite likely to hear in unprepared, colloquial speech, despite it being logically dubious and in formal registers also grammatically dubious.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the comma after "than" in "He is as clever as, if not cleverer than, his bother" really makes the phrase sound and look at best unnatural, at worst ungrammatical to me.

And so, I would simply say:

> "*He is as clever as, [**if not cleverer than**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=qIiXklkc0pYC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22clever+as+if+not+cleverer+than%22&source=bl&ots=g8KZLaOAiE&sig=dNeoPhrIPipxZtIFC-2lQvjkAiM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=uhdxU__4FqOc0AXEyYHIAw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22clever%20as%20if%20not%20cleverer%20than%22&f=false) his brother*."
>
> "*Ranjeet is as fast as, or perhaps faster than Robit*."

As for moving the parenthetic clause to the end, it indeed is perfectly OK, as digitig correctly pointed out. That said, aside from the slight difference in emphasis, I don't think it adds any style improvement at all to the original phrase.